# can we reuse same code for all text area in page?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am using same JS code for each text area by capturing their value with different variable.

Is there any way that same code can re-use for each text area in page, as I having 20/30 text area per page. Please do suggest?

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" class="txtClass" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
<textarea id="TextArea2" class="txtClass" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
```

**JS Script**

```
objTextBox1 = document.getElementById("TextArea1");
oldValue1 = objTextBox1.value;

objTextBox2 = document.getElementById("TextArea2");
oldValue2 = objTextBox2.value;

var somethingChanged = false;

function track_change()
  {
    //for text box 1 change
    if(objTextBox1.value != oldValue1)
     {
       oldValue1 = objTextBox1.value;
       somethingChanged = true;
     }

    //for text box 2 change
    if(objTextBox2.value != oldValue2)
     {
       oldValue2 = objTextBox2.value;
       somethingChanged = true;
     }

   } 

  setInterval (function() { track_change()}, 100);
```

Comment: You always can reuse duplicated code.

Comment: That's not jQuery. Have you tagged your question with jQuery because you want to use it, or because you've confused JS with jQuery?

Comment: Why not listening to change event?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, instead of `document.getElementById("TextArea1");` use `$('#TextArea1')`

Comment: @Ricardo, that's my question, how to use duplicate code?

Comment: each Text Area has "class" attribute with same value

Comment: check my answer, maybe could help @user584018

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **change** event instead of tracking the change using setInterval to keep a tab on the changes..

```
$(function() {

    var somethingChanged = false;
    $('.txtClass').on('change', function(){
         somethingChanged = true;
        alert('Something Changed !!');
    });    

});​
```

[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/XCwLQ/)

Using Only Javascript .. You can try this

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" class="txtClass" cols="20" onchange="Changed(this)" rows="2"></textarea>
<textarea id="TextArea2" class="txtClass" cols="20" onchange="Changed(this)" rows="2"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var somethingChanged = false;
    function Changed(elem){

        somethingChanged = true;
        alert('Something Changed !!');
    };

</script>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You originally tagged your question as `jquery`.  You are not using `jquery`.  If you do, it'd be very simple to cut down on code duplication:

```
$("textarea").data('oldValue', function () { $(this).val(); })
   .on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('oldValue') {
         somethingChanged = true;
      }
   });
```

If you actually can't or don't want to use jQuery, you can still do it using `getElementsByTagName` or possibly `querySelectorAll`.

```
for (elem in document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')) {
   elem.data.oldValue = this.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: event not fired! One thing I miss to underline that .... all text area has feed with spell check 3rd party control, that's why Text Area become HIDDEN and a DIV is generate...Due to HIDE a Trigger is applied in my JS code, now please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the jquery binding of elements. More details here http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$('.txtClass').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

What more do you need to do with the variables you're storing and updating the values in?

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is wrong because when using your code, at first time, `somethingChanged` is `false` then when something has changed in the `textarea`, `somethingChanged` is `true` but `oldValue1` is the same as `objTextBox1.value`, this means the values are always the same and you are not detecting any "*old*" value, you are just detecting if something has changed in the `textarea` and this will always give you `true`.

**e.g**

Result using your code:

**oldValue1**: oscar / **objTextBox1.value**: oscar /
**somethingChanged** = true;

***(because "oscar" will always be "oscar", so you are not getting any old value)***

If you plan to get the old value, the correct logic will be something like this:

**oldValue1:** osca / **objTextBox1.value**: oscar /
**somethingChanged** = true;

***(because "osca" is the old text before finishing writing "oscar", and if this is the situation you want to achieve, you need to make again your logic)***

---

According to what I wrote, you dont need to use any `setInterval`, I just try to recreate what you need to do using `keyUp`, take a look:

### **Using javascript, not jQuery:**

*Explanation*: when user finished typing something (`keyup`), doesn't matter which `textarea`, the detect method will look for the `defaultValue` (`textarea` value in first moment) and check if it has changed.

***HTML:***

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" class="txtClass" cols="20" rows="2" onKeyup="detect(this);"></textarea>
<textarea id="TextArea2" class="txtClass" cols="20" rows="2" onKeyup="detect(this);"></textarea>
```

***JS:***

```
function detect(elem){
    if(elem.defaultValue != elem.value){
        somethingChanged = true;
        alert("text changed!");
    }
};
```

---

### **Using jQuery:**

Just for this case I will recommend you this plugin:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/javascripts/plugins/jquery.textchange.min.js

Then you just do this:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/bs8hJ/2/

```
$('textarea').bind('textchange', function (event, previousTxt) {
    somethingChanged = true;
});
```

---

Comment: guys....as i m apply some 3rd party on that text area, hence it will become hidden at run time. now no event will be execute, hence we need to trigger the event, for that here "SetInterval" used...please suggest...

Comment: If there is no event executed and as I understood you wrote that this textarea is hidden, then why and how are you trying to evaluate if the value changed (because It must be visible to give it a value right?) otherwise if you are using this just to store something in the process, maybe an input hidden will be good (correct me if wrong)

Comment: well...I m just trying to do is there any change (delete one char, add new char or even roll back the change, anything) with the content of text area, I want to set a variable True to prompt alert to user that there is some change, save before quit the page...

Comment: I think you have to do again your code, sorry. Your question is not exactly as you want to achieve and if you read what I put, your logic is wrong, good luck